# Website hosted on EC2, domain registered at Gandi.net.. how do I properly configure the domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, domain

First time ever doing this. Basically, I'm trying to figure out how to properly configure everything so that the domain sends requests to EC2.

Can I simply use the instance's Public DNS? If yes, where should it go in Gandi? I tried putting this to zone file's A record, but it wants an IP address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a elastic ip address, which you then assign to your instance. Then setup an A-Record pointing at this ip.

Comment: Hi, thanks! So I can't use the public DNS of the form xxxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com given by Amazon?

Comment: Elastic ips are free- as long as they are assigned to an instance. It's not good practice to use the DNS form- far as I am aware

Answer (score 1):

You need DNS servers to point to **or** as your trying to do you need to set that A record as an elastic IP which you then attach to your instance.

Comment: Will the xxxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com "public dns" work as pointable DNS, if yes, where in Gandi I define this?